# Wordpress Disuqs plugin not working properly

Tags: plugins, wordpress, wordpress-theming, disqus

Hi I am new to working with Disqus plugin and I have a strange behavior.
After I installed the plugin and configured it it show comments without andy styling and without even the add comment textarea just showing the comment and comment author name only

It doesn't even include any scripts related to Disqus plugin .

here is the code I used in single.php

```
 <?php comments_template(); ?>
```

here is the result I get

[image]

I have tried to disable the plugin and re-enable it then I try using the twentyfifteen theme and every thing worked fine with it but with my theme I get the issue 
Any help will be appreciated , Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix for me was to uncheck External Javascript Files option in the plugin settings panel.

It says "Disable this if are not seeing Disqus appear on pages that normally have comments. This will fix the issue if your theme does not support the 'wp_enqueue_script' function, are caching your site on a CDN."

it works like a charm now!

Answer (score -1):

That's happening because the function comments_template() is associated/overridden with the template you're seeing now.

Go through your theme files and you shall find a template that's showing up to you right now.